# No message in msmq

Tags: c#, msmq

I writing a console app that add a message to local queue. But, no message is being inserted.

I created the queue as transactional and inserting like following:

```
      string path = @"FormatName:DIRECT=OS:computername\private$\myqueue";
        MessageQueue queue = new MessageQueue();
        queue.Path = path;            

        foreach (string msg in messages)
        {
            queue.Send("inputMessage", msg);

        }
```

Anything wrong with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easy one, this.
You are sending a non-transactional message to a transactional queue. MSMQ will discard the message.

Use the ["MessageQueue.Send(Object, MessageQueueTransaction)"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa329511%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) Method

If you enable Negative Source Journaling, you can look in the dead letter queue to see why messages gets discarded.

Cheers
John Breakwell

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the queue before you can send to it (it's a one time operation, unless you delete the queue):

```
MessageQueue queue;
if (MessageQueue.Exists(path))
  queue = new MessageQueue(path);
else
  queue = MessageQueue.Create(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

try swapping the order on your send.

I'd have to double check but i'm pretty sure the order is object, label

```
queue.Send(msg, "inputMessage");
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have transactional queues, make sure to check that you are using transactions

> ```
> using(MessageQueueTransaction tx = new MessageQueueTransaction()) {
>     tx.Begin();
>     queue.Send(message, tx);
>     tx.Commit(); 
> }
> ```

see more info in another post [Message does not reach MSMQ when made transactional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9911843/message-does-not-reach-msmq-when-made-transactional)